# What does JLabel.toString return?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, tostring

I would like to know what does the default `toString` function return when used for a `JLabel`.

Specifically what is `invalid` in the return line below?

```
javax.swing.JLabel[,40,200,10x10,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=25165832,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,horizontalAlignment=LEADING,horizontalTextPosition=TRAILING,iconTextGap=4,labelFor=,text=,verticalAlignment=CENTER,verticalTextPosition=CENTER]
```

Comment: This is where you visit GrepCode and examine the source yourself.

Comment: `invalid` tells you, that the component is not valid

Comment: Thanks. Already did it just redirects me to `swing.component` and there is no toString function explained.

Comment: It gets the `toString()` method from `java.awt.Component`, see : http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/Component.java#Component.toString%28%29

Comment: Just remember - you can OVERRIDE `toString()` method for EVERY class you declare. It becomes a String representation of that class. So, if you call `System.out.println(myClass)` or any similar method, the String that you constructed will be applied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can also type `new JLabel().toString();` in eclipse and place the cursor inside the `.toString()` part and press `F3`. this leads you to the source code as well. and the source code is:

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + '[' + paramString() + ']';
}
```

`paramString()` is defined as:

```
protected String paramString() {
    final String thisName = Objects.toString(getName(), "");
    final String invalid = isValid() ? "" : ",invalid";
    final String hidden = visible ? "" : ",hidden";
    final String disabled = enabled ? "" : ",disabled";
    return thisName + ',' + x + ',' + y + ',' + width + 'x' + height
            + invalid + hidden + disabled;
}
```

This should sum up what you want to know.

NOTE:
It will lead you to `java.awt.Component` because `JLabel` does inherit from it in a long way

Comment: And `CTRL + Click` or `CTRL + ALT + B` in IntelliJ.